# boost problem in windows 7

Tags: c++, boost

I have written the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/system/windows_error.hpp>

using namespace boost::system;

int main(){

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io,boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    std::cout<<"hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib'
```

I dont know how and what do, can you please explain what is happening and what steps I can take to fix it?

Comment: @algorithms: Are you using MSVC++ or g++?

Comment: visual c++  MSVC 2010 i have built all library  of boost version 1.44

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, for MSVC++ 2010

Under `Project Properties`, goto

`Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` and add there the path to the `*.lib` file (For example: `C:\boost_1_41_0\stage\lib`)

Comment: yes but in case of i indicate  full path of boost library itself  why not work? for example i have boost on desktop so i will indicate path
C:\Users\David\Desktop\boost_1_44_0

Comment: You have to add the `*.lib` file's path separately(to the linker search path) as I have suggested.

Comment: i have done but not works because i need other   linker path like network asio

Comment: @Algorithms: Add the `lib` directory's path. For example if `libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib` is present in `C:\Users\David\Desktop\boost_1_44_0\stage\lib` you have to add that.

Comment: i have indicate this link
C:\Users\David\Desktop\boost_1_44_0\stage\lib   but not works

Comment: @algorithms : What do mean by `indicate`?

Comment: my project name is networking.cpp so right click mouse
properties  include additional directories  and paste full path of *.lib  files

Comment: @algorithms : Do not right click on the `*.cpp` file. Right click on the project and then do whatever I have written in my answer.

Comment: i have accept but can't upvote because it requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the error message it compiles but can't find the boost compiled libraries.

These you have to build yourselves unless you can find them prebuilt.

IIRC boost are built using a tool called bjam. I think this explains it rather throughly: http://www.highscore.de/cpp/boostbuild/index.html.

After it's built you have to instruct the compiler to link it using the project properties.

Comment: ok listen guys i have downloaded  boost librarys and built it   so i dont  understand built again?ok i say directly show please exactly what to do    please help me

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you haven't built the libraries. You can get the pre-built libraries from [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) or you can build them yourself following the instructions at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I was working in one instance of Visual Studio 2010. When I started up another, to scrawl out a bit of code, I was shocked to see the same error message. Reset includes and lib (Project->NameofProject Properties then select VC++ Directories) and toggled back and forth between debug and release, at first just once, then a few more times, as I grew increasingly alarmed at none of this working.

Even though the IDE didn't report any activity ('Build Failed,' was all it said in the place where it shows includes/libs being enumerated) after a few minutes (of furious web browsing) I came back to discover that it had silently self-fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)